# Re-entering Schengen area after being out of the country for 90 days but before 180 days is up

Tags: schengen

Can you re-enter Schengen if for example you entered October 1st and left 60 days later December first but want to come back for another two months before the end of the 180 days?

Comment: The 180 days are a rolling window. At **any time** in Schengen you must have spent no more than 90 of the previous 180 days in Schengen on a C visa. So if you have been out 90 days you are definitively safe in this regard.

Comment: https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm